Which mixed precision setting is in effect when it is set both in accelerate config and TrainingArguments?
I am using both HuggingFace's transformers library and accelerate library.
When it comes to mixed precision setting, there are two places that I can set:

At accelerate config, in the interface below
Do you wish to use FP16 or BF16 (mixed precision)?
Please select a choice using the arrow or number keys, and selecting with enter
   no                                                                                                                                                  
   fp16                                                                                                                                                
➔  bf16
   fp8


In TrainingArguments, like
transformers.TrainingArguments(
    bf16=False,
    fp16=True
)



So my question is, the setting at which place will supersede the other and be in effect eventually?
For example, if in accelerate config I set bf16 but in TrainingArguments I set fp16, which one will be used?
I have tried to fix the setting in acclerate config and change the setting in TrainingArguments and did notice some speed change. So it seems that the setting in TrainingArguments supersedes. But I still want to get some confirmation.
